# Cocoa - Binding multiple custom NSTableCellViews of view based NSTableView with multiple Models using NSArrayController

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I would like to bind properties of multiple Models with **multiple** custom  NSTableView view based cells.

I have tried to use NSArrayController but unfortunately it expects a specific: "Class Name".

i've also tried to trick the NSArrayController and providing it a Class name of a Model which is a parent of all of the multiple Models but i've faced 2 problems:

1. in Bindings Inspector->Value->Model Key of any of the custom TableViewCell elements, i could select only the properties of the parent
2. during debugging, all of the values were not updated and were nil.

Any clues?

Comment: What is the content of the array controller?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of NSObjectManager's `objectClass`:

> The object class to use when creating new objects.

Don't let the arraycontroller create new objects. The object class is not used and it doesn't matter what it is.

1. You can type other key paths in the Bindings Inspector. A grey exclamation mark means 'Xcode cannot resolve the entered keypath'. If the keypath can be resolved at runtime, it is ok.